# How to excute Jquery plugin on an object added at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, runtime, textarea

I have a `JQuery` plugin that count the character in the `textarea` .
But if I added the textarea at run time using `append("<textarea></textarea>")` for example,.

How to execute this plugin on the appended `textarea` ?

```
$("textarea").charCount({
                        allowed: 200,       
                        warning: 30,
                        counterText: 'Characters left: '    
                });
```

adding textarea at runtime ..

```
$("#btnAddStep").click(function () {
                var text = "" +
                " <div class='row-fluid'>" +
                "   <div class='span10'>" +
                "      <input type='text' class='span12' placeholder='Type something…'>" +
                "  </div>" +
                " <div class='span2'>" +
                "    <div class='btn-group'>" +
                "        <button class='btn btn-mini' id='btnAddStep'><i class='icon icon-plus'></i></button>" +
                "        <button class='btn btn-mini'><i class='icon icon-minus'></i></button>" +
                "    </div>" +
                "  </div>" +
                " </div>" ;

                $("#response>#steps").append(text);
            });
```

Comment: You will need to delegate the handler for this to the document object using jQuery 1.7's `.on()` method, or for previous verison, the `.delegate()` method.

Comment: can you show me an example ??

Comment: I would need to see the handler that invokes the function to count the characters. Without, it's like pissing in the wind.

Comment: What is calling this function. Is it a click, what's the method to do this? Are you just looking to run this whenever a textarea is added to the DOM?

Comment: When click on a button I append the textarea to a div, yes  I just looking to run this whenever a textarea is added to the DOM?

Comment: Show me the click function for the button that appends the div and I will create an answer.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy check the updates please ...

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click event handler for the button that you use to add the textarea to the div, add a call to your plugin's method.

As I cannot see the entire code, I am going to assume that the plugin is automatically called at runtime as well, inside a `$(document).ready()` or something similar. If you add the textarea after this is called you will need to re-run the plugin.

All you will have to do is add the code you posted again to your click event code, but in the interest of efficiency, rather than running the plugin on every text area all over again, I suggest that you add another option to search for textareas with a particular class and then remove that class after the plugin is run on them. This way, you can give all your new text areas this class and after the plugin runs on them it will never look at them again.

Good luck!

EDIT: A friend of mine is looking over my shoulder and suggested that I clarify a bit: you will not have to modify your plugin in any way (granted, I cannot see the full code so I cannot be 100% sure of this, but let's just say that I'm 95% sure). What you would do is change the event handler (and also any call made in the document.ready - which, technically, is an event handler) like so:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function() {
    ...your code...
    $("#placeToAddNewTextArea").append("<textarea class="newTA"></textarea>");
    $("textarea.newTA").charCount({ ......... });
    $("textarea.newTA").removeClass("newTA");
});
```

In other words, you can use CSS as flags and create, use, and remove them all outside of the plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery SuperLive.

According to the authors:

> jQuery SuperLive is my favorite new plugin. Allen Mackley and I created this to solve a ton of applicate JS problems. We needed plugins to work no matter when elements existed on the page, AND, if attributes were ever added, the plugins should re-enable.
>
> SuperLive does all this.
>
> THIS DOES NOT WORK IN IE. ie doesn't support mutation events.
> Also requires jQuery 1.7

Demo video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh5mGR2GyLY

Download: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-superlive/downloads/list